# Table View with extra View. View keep resizing to maximum

Tags: ios, swift, view, resize, tableview

I have a tableview, that is working fine.  I have added a view to the top, so I can add some extra fields.  I can't post images yet, so going to try and describe.

Navigation Bar
View
TableView

When I build it, it looks good.. However when I run or close the project and reopen I get this:

Navigation Bar
View

TableView

With the view taking up the complete page, pushing the TableView to the very bottom.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix it?? I can resize it back to the size I want using the size inspector, but it doesn't keep the value.

I have built a test project with the same screen layout and it works perfectly. I can't see what is different between the two projects is.  Thanks

Comment: You should be able to post links to images hosted elsewhere. Are you saying this is an Xcode / storyboard issue, and you're using auto-layout?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was an auto layout problem..  After looking around the web, and trying various solutions I decided to use a view controller, and add my own tableview and tablefviewcell to that, along with my other labels and buttons.  Once I built the methods the first time, I found this to be much cleaner solution, than attempting to mess around with the tableviewcontroller.